# Bitwise and Reversal (&11111111)

Tags: bit-manipulation

If there is a long bit string say, 10010101010110101 and you do

`10010101010110101 & 11111111`

How can you reverse this process if the bit string is truncated?
I was taught that if you do this operation, the resulting bit string will only have 8 bits.

Comment: You can't. It's a "lossy" operation :-)

Comment: This is like asking “if I have the sum of three numbers and only know one of the original numbers, how do I reverse the addition to find out what the other two were”. The answer is you can't, for the same reasons. If you need it to be reversible, you must store the original…

Comment: I'm aware that you lose data when using the & operator, but that's only if there are 0s in the bit string right? I should have been more clear, but I meant to ask if there are ways undo the the operation given that one of the bit strings is something like 11111111, and the other bit string is longer.

Comment: Anywhere that isn't a 1... is a 0.

Answer (score 0):

The AND operation:

```
  | 0  1
--|-----
0 | 0  0
1 | 0  1
```

An output `1` => both inputs were `1`.

An output `0` => the inputs were any of three possibilities: `{0, 1}`, `{1, 0}` or `{0, 0}`.

You cannot map back from a `0` to the original bit. The mapping is many to one.